# making different parts of an SVG image clickable

Tags: svg

I have searched through the net and have come to discover that images are made clickable when they are converted to SVG format, however I am still not sure how to do this.
the image below for example, I need every box to be clickable, how do you go about doing this and is there any app that can help me, thank you in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KZoq.jpg)

Comment: What do you want to happen when a box is clicked?

Comment: I want it to take me to another page

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an SVG.  But you would probably find it much easier to do with an [HTML image map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map).

Comment: I ended up really using the image maps

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to edit the SVG itself you can wrap each element with an anchor tag.

```html
<svg>
  <a href="www.link1.com">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="60" height="50" fill="#ddd">
  </a>
  <a href="www.link2.com">
    <rect x="75" y="10" width="60" height="50" fill="#ddd">
  </a>
</svg>
```

Otherwise you can use Javascript to add a click handler to each element.

```js
document.getElementById("rect1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.open('www.link1.com')
});

document.getElementById("rect2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.open('www.link2.com')
});
```

```html
<svg>
    <rect id="rect1" x="10" y="10" width="60" height="50" fill="#ddd"/>
    <rect id="rect2" x="75" y="10" width="60" height="50" fill="#ddd"/>
</svg>
```